# taskhostw using a lot of disk and doing something on windows.old folder

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, process-explorer, resource-monitor

I found my windows 10 machine being very slow and using a lot of hard drive.

Task manager, Disk is reporting 100% usage.

I open up Resource monitor, select disk tab. and sort write column.
System and taskhostw.exe are using most of disk.

I check taskhostw, and there are a dozen of entries with references to C:\windows.old\... files

I thought this windows folder was supposed to be dormant, but clearly isn't.

Running disk clean up, clean up system files, and select to remove old versions of windows seems to have resolved the problem

Is this an OS problem? or a sign of something else wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps Windows Defender is busily checking all of `Windows.old`.

It seems like you have just completed a major Windows upgrade.
In this case, I would leave it to do its work.
It might be too soon to get rid of the old Windows version and give up on the
possibility to rollback to it if you encounter serious problems.

If everything is OK after about a week, you may use Disk Cleanup to reduce
`Windows.old`. This is not really necessary, as Windows will do it automatically
28 days after the upgrade. It is recommended to wait for this to happen,
to leave all options open until then.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I wasn't aware the taskhostw.exe was used by Windows Defender. I have now a suspicion that it could be a mining trojan.
https://howtoremove.guide/taskhostw-exe/

If this is true, how the heck got into my PC and why Windows Defender does not spot it. Clearly, I have to keep an eye on the PC activity

Comment: That you should do, and Windows Defender (or any other) does not spot everything.